# Javascript RegExp - extract phone numbers from string

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I have the following working regex to extract a lot of phone numbers in different formats.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SB5Ly/4/

```
var regex = new RegExp(
            "\\+?\\(?\\d*\\)? ?\\(?\\d+\\)?\\d*([\\s./-]?\\d{2,})+",
            "g"
        );
....
```

(If the script didn't load, press the "Run" button from the top menu)

As you can see in the example (by following the link), the last 2-3 phone number formats (var phoneNumbers) doesn't match the used regex.
You can test the regex modifying it in the script and running it.

So i need a regex that match all the enumerated phone number formats (to extract them from an entire webpage (document.body.innerHTML)).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how prescriptive you want to be, but this matches all your examples:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\+?\\(?\\d*\\)? ?\\(?\\d+\\)?\\d*([\\s./-]?\\d{2,})+", "g");
```

See a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SB5Ly/#share) of this regex.

---

One small bug with your regex: When wanting to include a literal dash in a character class, either escape it or place it first or last.

You had `[\\s-.]`, which is incorrect. It should be either `[\\s.-]`, `[-\\s.]` or `[\\s\\-.]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @bohemian.
Actually i forgot to mention that i didn't want to extract the country code, too. But this helps me a lot.
If you can post me another regexp to extract the phone number without the country code, will be the best.
And thanks for the remarks, too.

Comment: Ok, i change my code to work with the country codes. Only for the curiosity, can you provide the new regex to exclude the country codes? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have to remark a problem, in the live demo you provided, all the strings were matched, but when i run the above provided script, the next strings doesn't match: 
(0490)260722
(0)442207724
+33 (0)442207724
Can you help me with this?

Comment: I can help with vountry cides, but what exactly do you mean by "exclude"? I will look into your new examples.

Comment: I have looked into your new examples you're having problems with. I tried them and they match for new: See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/rduS37WC86). Tell me more about how/what you're matching

Comment: You can try this little script with the problematic strings here: http://jsfiddle.net/
If it is possible help me only to match these type of phone numbers, too. Let the country code problem away. It isn't a problem anymore ;)

Comment: I want to help you, but I just don't understand you. Edit the question to explain in detail, with examples of input you want to match and examples of input you want to not match.

Comment: I am edited the question. You have to follow the link to see what i'm talking about. There is a little example with some of my phone number formats that i want to match with a super regex. These phone numbers will be on a webpage that i will parse to extract them.

Comment: I have changed the regex to made your new examples work and updated the link to go to jsfiddle.

Comment: My fault, i forgot to mention you have to push the update button on the menu to save the modifications :(
Now i see only the original version
Thank you!

Comment: I updated the example (put your new regex) and extended the array with the phone number formats to be matched. Can you take a look pls how to match the next few numbers. Thank you!

Comment: If it is possible take account of the phone numbers will starts only with "0", "+" or "(" and not other digits.

Comment: One extra thing, the match should have a minimum of 9 characters !? What do you think? Because for now all the numbers (like postcodes) will be matched in the innerHTML of the <body>.

Comment: maybe we can edit this regex which working pretty well but didn't allow parentheses and not return the country code...
    "(?:0|(?:00[\\s-.]?|\\+\\s?)?33[\\s-.]?)"
    + "[1-9](?:[\\s-./]?[0-9]{2}){4}"

Comment: At this point it's starting to get a bit silly. You want to accept basically almost any combination of digits, spaces, brackets and hyphens with an optional plus sign - ie `^+?[-()\d ]{8,}`. To progress, either provide lots of sample input that should **not** match, or use one of the many standard phone number regexes available on the web or here at SO.