# Checking for phone number in a large string of text

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I am using google-libphonenumber to find out whether a string of large text contain phone numbers or not, if I use "isValidNumber", then it expects only a string of phone number and not a complete string of large text that "might" contain phone number.

So, my query is which functionality of google-libphonenumber to use when I have a large string of text that might contain phone number(s).

PS : I have to handle this in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a similar question was already asked

[Javascript RegExp - extract phone numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006152/javascript-regexp-extract-phone-numbers-from-string)

check the answers there, they might give you what you need.

Comment: The answers in the given link contains solutions that takes "only" phone number as a string, but my string is a text that "might" contain phone number as well, I need to check whether the string "contains" a valid phone number. The solutions there ask us to remove all other alpha characters other than numerics and then check for the phone number in the string, but in that case numbers like (011)-28888888,9898989898 will convert to 011288888889898989898 and that will be an invalid phone number, but in actuality it contains two valid phone numbers, so that's the problem.